# Where we need use VACUUM

Tags: android, sqlite

```
    databaseInstance.execSQL("PRAGMA auto_vacuum = FULL");
```

Currently i am using it after creating DB and before creating Tables of DB. I did some transaction with DB and it size with all these data is 34016 Byte and then i delete all these data then ideally DB size should get down but what is happening that :- **Data get deleted and size get increase 43232 Byte.**
What is wrong please help me. Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: Check whether it succeeded by running the query `PRAGMA auto_vacuum`. Did it?

Comment: ok.. in SQLite manager first i run PRAGMA auto_vacuum = FULL then no any output and after that i run only PRAGMA auto_vacuum...Last one shows 0 as output in SQLite Manager....

Comment: I am using this VACUUM first time and i am bit confuse . what is happening and which is better.??Please help me

Comment: Why do you think you need to use any kind of vacuuming?

Comment: Because even after deleting data from DB its size get increase day-by-day..

Comment: Free pages get reused. The growth will not be unbounded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58682/discussion-between-blue-green-and-cl).

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum) says:

> Auto-vacuuming is only possible if the database stores some additional information that allows each database page to be traced backwards to its referrer. Therefore, auto-vacuuming must be turned on before any tables are created. It is not possible to enable or disable auto-vacuum after a table has been created.

This is a little bit misleading.
"Before any tables are created" actually should say "before the database is actually created".
You should execute it directly after opening the new database, before setting anything else, and before the first transaction is begun.

If you are using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, put it into the `onConfigure` callback.

Comment: I am using GREENDAO and i am using it in onCreate() block of DAOMaster class. Is it correct??

Comment: Apparently not. AFAICS GreenDAO does not support the `onConfigure()` callback.

Comment: ok.. so what i should used PRAGMA auto_vacuum = FULL or PRAGMA auto_vacuum.?? which is better?

Comment: That depends. In most cases, you shouldn't use either.

Comment: Still i am struggling with this issue. I didn't find any of concrete solution.